# How add new column in to existing druid schema?

Tags: druid

I create a schema and i add 1TB data to druid schema. then the log file version was upgraded and new two columns was added. then i want to add that data to druid schema. but couldn't yet.

Answer (score 7):

In order to add a new column to existing datasource you need to follow the below steps:

1. Go to the `Tasks` menu in druid console.
2. From the listed datasources, go to the 'Actions' column in the last of the datasource in which you want to add the column.
3. There will be a magnifying glass like button, click on that to copy the existing payload.
4. Copy the payload in notepad and add the 2 columns to *"dimensions"* array.
5. Copy the updated payload and submit it via `Submit Supervisor` button.

You'll find the new columns in the datasource which you can verify by querying the datasource in query section of druid.