# Apache Druid Schema Column Addition

Tags: druid

Can we add column in Druid Datasource ? I want to add column, do I need to drop and load data with new column or any alter command available ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557285/how-add-new-column-in-to-existing-druid-schema

Comment: Thank you so much for providing above link, but immediately column is not showing in druid. Even when I query , it is saying column doesnot exist. Any other link ? some where we need to set refresh ? commit ?

Comment: Did you see a new datasource getting added? Or are the Segments showing they are completely available?

Comment: Column  I am trying to add. As per link, I have added and submitted Supervisor. Showing UNHEALTHY_TASKS. IS it bcz of my druid problem ?

Comment: I am sorry, it is working fine. I just added column but definition of that column [ whether string or numeric is not defined properly.] This is the reason giving above error. It is wroking fine.